# Assign values returning from Python to JQuery

Tags: python

I am still new in python and I have a code that read the geometry of the shapefile, then do calculations from 4 functions then return these values to a table in JQuery. How do I assign values returned to a row of a table.

```
...
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Results.php",
    data: { 
       city: city
    },
    dataType: 'json',
```

PHP code...

```
...Results.php
$command = shell_exec('python ../spatialCal.py ' . $geom);
if($command){
     $resp['success'] = true; 
     $resp['results'] = $command;
....
....
header('Content-type: application/json',true);
print json_encode($resp);
```

Python

```
....
def main(): 
   informalRead()  
   lowcostRead() 
   builtRead() 
   villageRead() 

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

I fairly new in python world

Comment: Your question title provides no attempt to do what you intent to with what you have in **Python Code**

Comment: The title could have been long soI tried to put all that in description

Comment: You will need to explain in more detail how the parts that you show in your question are interacting between them. After than could you clarify what exactly is the issue you are facing? What isn't working as expected?

Comment: I am sending a data to php then from php retrieve additional data then pass that data to python, I want the results to be populated to the table